# MongoDB and GridFS with Java: Saving multiple files at once

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs, mongodb-java, mongo-java

I'm wondering how I can save multiple files at once *without* using a `for` loop or something like that) using MongoDB, GridFS and the MongoDB Native Java Driver.

I want to measure the time (benchmark) without measuring the for loop time.

Comment: The GridFS methods insert one file per call. If you're measuring the time to insert multiple files, the time to iterate between them (which will be 0 compared to actually reading, chunking, inserting) is rightfully part of the measurement anyways.

Comment: This is the second time you helped me today. Thank you for the help and your time. MongoDB just beat MySQL according to my tests again. =) Excellent product!